# How can I implement a while loop using flex/bison?

Tags: while-loop, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I could do simple scanner and parser using bison and flex like a simple calculator for example I can give input (to the exe which was generated after compiling the lex.yy.c and y.tab.c), 3+4*5, the exe would display the result as 23. But I don't know how to do the following:

```
x = 0;
while (x < 3) {
    print x;
    x = x + 1;
}
```

using flex and bison. 
I want the exe generated to print x, until the while loop condition fails. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a While Loop in Bison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200808/parsing-a-while-loop-in-bison)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to build an interpreter. What you would need is 1) to implement a symbol table and 2) define interpreter nodes derived from a common base class. Each node would have, e.g., an "execute" method.

You'd use your Bison/Yacc parser to build the node tree. Then "execute" the root of the tree.

Comment: I know this is late, but, when discussing with my Prof., he told me, there is no need for me to create the syntax, as instructions are simple. I don't need even the `print x` instruction.

Comment: the format is like this : `while (cond) {instruction}`, the possible conditions are `x > const` or `x < const` or `x != const` and for instructions: `if (op = '+') {x = x + const;}` or `if (op = '-') {x = x - const;}`.